# Running one-off command for docker dyno on heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

Nothing happens when I run a worker dyno from the `cli` or the `scheduler` add-on.

I've tried to enable or disable the dyno, but it does nothing for the one-off and the scheduler.
When enabling dyno, heroku starts it (not as one-off or scheduler) and command from worker (specified as `CMD` in Dockerfile) runs just fine.
Running `run` with command also doesn't help.
Log output for such runs is like this:

```
2019-09-04T18:30:34.176982+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8210]: State changed from starting to complete

2019-09-04T18:30:34.153189+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `/opt/app/run.sh` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com

2019-09-04T18:41:15.398424+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4565]: State changed from starting to complete

2019-09-04T18:41:15.354628+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `/opt/app/run.sh` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
```

Log output for the run after enabling dyno is like this:

```
2019-09-04T18:45:39.694515+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user kjiec4@gmail.com

2019-09-04T18:45:44.856180+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `/opt/app/run.sh`

2019-09-04T18:45:45.474477+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up

2019-09-04T18:45:47.252345+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.license.VersionPrinter - Flyway Community Edition 6.0.1 by Boxfuse

2019-09-04T18:45:48.221494+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseFactory - Database: jdbc:postgresql://ec2-176-34-184-174.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/dc9jgd0q28f9sd (PostgreSQL 11.5)

2019-09-04T18:45:48.298740+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate - Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.037s)

2019-09-04T18:45:48.321407+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.schemahistory.JdbcTableSchemaHistory - Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" ...

2019-09-04T18:45:48.383992+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Current version of schema "public": << Empty Schema >>

2019-09-04T18:45:48.392490+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Migrating schema "public" to version 1 - Create news table

2019-09-04T18:45:48.422169+00:00 app[worker.1]: [main] INFO org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "public" (execution time 00:00.052s)

2019-09-04T18:46:08.425628+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed

2019-09-04T18:46:08.509950+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2019-09-04T18:46:08.401741+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0

2019-09-04T18:46:12.919303+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `/opt/app/run.sh`

2019-09-04T18:46:13.527541+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

The last one is an expected behavior.

I'm trying to run it like this:

```
heroku run worker
```

And like this:

```
heroku run worker /opt/app/run.sh
```

The scheduler command specified simply as: `worker`.

What should I do to run docker container as one-off in heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I found out, I've done everything wrong.
To run one-off from the `cli` one need to specify process type as a parameter:

```
heroku run worker --type=worker
```

As for `scheduler` addon, it only works with `web` dynos as stated in the docs:

> If you are using Heroku Scheduler and Container Registry as your deployment method, your task must be accessible from the web image. There is no way to specify a non-web image for task execution.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler